# Logstash how to get the last occurance of a regex match?

Tags: regex, git, logstash

So this is sort of a weird request. I have a logstash file that reads off a jenkins build and extracts a commit_id from the console output. This is a sample of the type of output I am talking about:

```
17:11:07  Checking out Revision 071b1f53bab3c3453z46afe40c4e3068zc513eb4 (logstash_upgrade)
17:11:07   > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
17:11:07   > git checkout -f 071b1f53bab3c3453z46afe40c4e3068zc513eb4
17:11:07  Commit message: "Aqua scan"


17:11:07  Checking out Revision 071b1f5abab3c3a53e46afe40c4e30685ca13eb4 (logstash_upgrade)
17:11:07   > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
17:11:07   > git checkout -f 071b1f53bab3c3453e46afe40a4e30685c5a3eb4
17:11:07  Commit message: "real commit"
```

This is my grok match that I am trying to extract the commit id above:

```
grok {
    match => { "message_string" => "(?<GIT_COMMIT>(?<=Checking out Revision )\w*)"}
}
```

Here's the issue. There are multiple occurrences of the string "Checking out Revision ". Therefore our logstash will pick up the first occurrence of it and match the GIT_COMMIT to that id. The issue is that sometimes the first commit_id will not be the correct one, that is simply the commit_id of the security scan we run.

It would be ideal if I could find the *LAST* instance of "Checking out Revision " and match THAT commit_id to GIT_COMMIT.

However, I'm not sure if this is even possible through logstash as I can't find any documentation on it. And unfortunately there's no way to change the pattern as it's usually going to be the same format from the first to last occurrence of the string.

I would appreciate if anyone knew of a way to always match this grok-match to the last instance of the string found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
grok { match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA}(?<GIT_COMMIT>(?<=Checking out Revision )\w*)"} }
```

GREEDYDATA keeps consuming characters right up to the point where the rest of the regular expression stops matching. So it consumes everything up to the last place where your lookahead matches.

Comment: Interesting! So it is meant to scan up until the last regex match and capture the last value to it? Will test it now but this is exactly what I would need.

Comment: Looks like it worked exactly as I needed! Thank you